# Need text to overlay tikz header

Tags: tikz-pgf, overlays, covers

I'm trying to create a title page for a document but I'm having some trouble with the background imaging overlaying the text.

This is what it's looking like:

[image]

As you can see the words fall under the blue area instead of on top. I'd like to have the words on top of the blue box on the left and just have the entire tikz picture as a background.

Here's my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=2.3cm,tmargin=2cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[contents= ,color=white,scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{parskip}
\definecolor{altncolor}{rgb}{.8,0,0}

\usepackage[absolute]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{4cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{5mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner

\definecolor{bluey}{RGB}{0,121,194} %Alcon color
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\definecolor{alightb}{RGB}{223,233,243}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}   

\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[bluey]
          (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --
          ([yshift=-40pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) --
          ([yshift=-40pt]current page.south west|-current page text area.south west) -- cycle;
        \node[yshift=0.5cm,font=\bfseries\color{white}] at (current page.south) {\fontsize{15}{24}\selectfont};;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\HeaderCurve{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path [fill=alightb]
              ([xshift=0cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=10cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=10cm]current page.south west) -- ([xshift=0cm]current page.south west) -- cycle;
        \path [fill=lightgray]
              ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) .. controls (4,9) .. (current page.north east) --
              ([yshift=-9.5cm]current page.north east) .. controls (2,5.7) ..
              ([yshift=-10.5cm]current page.north west) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
% add header depending on the value of the page modulo 3
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderCurve}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=2\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderHalf}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=3\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderCurve}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=4\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderHalf}}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \BgMaterial
}
% add common footer for all pages
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \backgroundsetup{contents=\Footer}
  \BgMaterial
}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{2.cm}

\begin{textblock}{2}(2,3)
HEADER ONE

\lipsum[2]
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need is the `overlay` option for `textpos`:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[hmargin=0.5cm,bmargin=2.3cm,tmargin=2cm,centering]{geometry}
\usepackage[contents= ,color=white,scale=1,opacity=1,angle=0]{background}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{here}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{parskip}
\definecolor{altncolor}{rgb}{.8,0,0}

\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}

\setlength{\TPHorizModule}{4cm}
\setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
\textblockorigin{5mm}{10mm} % start everything near the top-left corner

\definecolor{bluey}{RGB}{0,121,194} %Alcon color
\definecolor{lightgray}{RGB}{235,235,235}
\definecolor{alightb}{RGB}{223,233,243}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{atbegshi}   

\newcommand\Footer{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \fill[bluey]
          (current page.south west) -- (current page.south east) --
          ([yshift=-40pt]current page.south east|-current page text area.south east) --
          ([yshift=-40pt]current page.south west|-current page text area.south west) -- cycle;
        \node[yshift=0.5cm,font=\bfseries\color{white}] at (current page.south) {\fontsize{15}{24}\selectfont};;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newcommand\HeaderCurve{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
        \path [fill=alightb]
              ([xshift=0cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=10cm]current page.north west) -- ([xshift=10cm]current page.south west) -- ([xshift=0cm]current page.south west) -- cycle;
        \path [fill=lightgray]
              ([yshift=-2cm]current page.north west) .. controls (4,9) .. (current page.north east) --
              ([yshift=-9.5cm]current page.north east) .. controls (2,5.7) ..
              ([yshift=-10.5cm]current page.north west) -- cycle;
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}

\pagestyle{empty}
% add header depending on the value of the page modulo 3
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \ifnum\value{page}=1\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderCurve}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=2\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderHalf}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=3\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderCurve}}
  \else  
  \ifnum\value{page}=4\relax
    \backgroundsetup{contents={\HeaderHalf}}
  \fi\fi\fi\fi
  \BgMaterial
}
% add common footer for all pages
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \backgroundsetup{contents=\Footer}
  \BgMaterial
}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{2.cm}

\begin{textblock}{2}(2,3)
HEADER ONE

\lipsum[2]
\end{textblock}

\end{document}
```

[image]